# pdo select a row if it contains one word of a string

Tags: php, mysql, string, select, pdo

I have a mysql table where users have a column with there favorit game.
They are saved like this:

```
id     username     games
1      user1        ,game1, game2, game3
2      user2        ,game2, game4
3      user3        ,game4, game1, game3
```

Now I want to select all users with at least one game as same as me.

```
$mygames = ,game2, game5

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE games = ?????");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
```

It should give me user1 and user2 because both contain game2 and I too!
How can I do that?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Storing the games as a csv is a poor design. Storing them as separate, multiple rows, makes it easier to do these types of searches.

Comment: Because of your data model, which violates the idea behind relation database design, you now run into an issue which makes the query very complex and expensive. I suggest you redesign your data and move the games into a separate relational table. That way your query will get as easy as a simple WHERE clause.

Comment: @arkascha - Yes and no... MySQL 5.7 supports JSON field type, so does postgre. Which breaks the rules of relational database design. Dependent on what data you are storing, and how you will be querying - then above-mentioned implementation **may** be perfectly fine. No point adding joins for the sake of joining and adding unneeded complexity. e.g. if tables are v small. Also, sometimes, it may be more efficient not to normalise fully.

Comment: @Gravy I don't want to argue about every single situation. But please note that what the OP has stored is _not_ json, it is something half baken resembling csv data. That is not efficient _especially_ in the situation the OP is in.

Comment: @arkascha - I agree with you. But you don't know where the OP got the data from, and that's not part of the question. I also upvoted your comment btw.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution

```
$mygames = ,game2, game5
$ug = explode(",", $mygames); //each word is splitted at the ,
$ug = array_filter($ug); //every empty array is deleted

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach ($users as $row) { 

$usg = explode(",", $row['games']); //each word is splitted at the ,
$usg = array_filter($usg);          //every empty array is deleted
$gsame= count(array_intersect($usg, $ug)) > 0; //if a user has at least one game as me it counts(onegame=1, twogames=2 etc...)

if($gsame > 0) { //if gsam is more than 0 it displays the array
<html></html>
}
```

Hope this helps some of you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Like statement, example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE game LIKE ? OR game LIKE ?";
$params = array("%,game2%", "%,game5%");
$statement = $handle->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex?

`select * FROM users where games REGEXP 'game4|game2';` if you want all rows containing game4 or game2 for example.

So your php needs to construct the regexp.

```
<?php

$games = ['game2', 'game4']; // an array of the required games

$regexp = implode('|', $games); // converts array to string with pipe as delimiter

echo ($regexp); // outputs 'game2|game4'
```

So your mysql now becomes

`$sql = 'select * FROM users where games REGEXP '. $regexp .';`

Answer (score -1):

As Matt said, using LIKE statement

in a better & scalable way:

```
$mygames = ",game2, game5"; // or whatever

// split & trim the gamenames
$games = array_map('trim',split(trim($mygames, ','))); 

// for ANY number of games you have, set the condition that selects anyone who have ANY of them.
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE " . substr(str_repeat(" games LIKE ? OR ", count($games)), 0, -3));
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: also it is better to redesign the structure of the database so you don't store the gamenames in one column separated by ,.

Comment: "in a "better", scalable and insecure way" you mean?